# Varnish not loading content from cache when refreshing manually

Tags: magento2, full-page-cache, varnish

We have setup varnish on our magento AWS server with nginx ssl configuration.
Varnish works fine on all other pages except the homepage.

Case 1 - Refresh the page with reload button on browser - TTFB - 13 Seconds

Case 2 - Refresh the page by clicking on Home link or Logo link - TTFB - 2 ms

Huge difference between these 2 cases is our problem.
We have lots of content on the homepage but it loads perfectly when reloading with home link or logo link.
But when we try to reload with ctrl + R or reload button from browser it takes nearly 13-15 sec to load the page.

This is not observed on the other pages link PDP or PLP where with both cases TTFB is less than 5ms everytime.

Can anyone suggest what's the problem here?

Here's the default.vcl

https://pastebin.com/4kYZL8Tk

Comment: Add your (custom) Magento 2 VCL to the question.

Comment: Added a default.vcl file @DanilaVershinin

Answer (score 0):

In terms of performance I would disregard the browser caching aspect. What matters more is whether or not Varnish caches the homepage.

Based on what I'm reading, I'm assuming this is not the case. There are various reasons for this *(for example a `Set-Cookie` header that is set by Magento for the homepage)*.

Let's figure out what's going on by using `varnishlog`. Assuming the homepage is problematic in terms of caching, please run the following command:

```
varnishlog -g request -q "ReqUrl eq '/'"
```

This command will filter out requests for the homepage and will group output per request. Please share the logging output.

> Before you run the `varnishlog` command, please ensure the cache is empty. We want to see logs for the first attempt at storing the homepage in cache.